# Close MySQL connection using node-mysql in gcloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, node-mysql

I have hosted an application in gcloud which uses mysql. But when the function crashes (error/exceptions) I need to end the connection. When the function gets crashed the logs emits :

```
error: Function worker killed by signal: SIGTERM
```

So how can I close my mysql connection (connection.end()) before the function gets terminated ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can end the connection when your app crashes. But maybe you can use `mysql.createPool(...);` rather then `mysql.createConnection(...);`

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});
```

This way you can set [pooling options](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options) for the connection and let the MySQL sort of manages the termination.